# Error 1064 - syntax error near " during trigger creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting this error:
**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7**

on the following query:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger UpdateTrigger 
    after update
        on reserva for each row
begin
IF NEW.reserva_valida = 0 THEN
    DELETE FROM companhia_aerea.venda 
    where companhia_aerea.venda = NEW.reserva_id;
END IF;
end;
DELIMITER ;
```

this is how I created both tables involved :

RESERVA:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companhia_aerea`.`reserva` (
  `reserva_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reserva_data_validade` DATE NOT NULL,
  `reserva_valida` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `reserva_voo_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `reserva_venda_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reserva_id`),
  INDEX `fk_reserva_voo1_idx` (`reserva_voo_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_reserva_venda1_idx` (`reserva_venda_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reserva_voo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`reserva_voo_id`)
    REFERENCES `companhia_aerea`.`voo` (`voo_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reserva_venda1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`reserva_venda_id`)
    REFERENCES `companhia_aerea`.`venda` (`venda_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

VENDA :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS companhia_aerea.venda;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companhia_aerea`.`venda` (
  `venda_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reserva_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `venda_parcelas` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`venda_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to a column in the `where` clause of the `delete`, not the table.  A table alias will help:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger UpdateTrigger 
    after update
        on reserva for each row
begin
    IF NEW.reserva_valida = 0 THEN
        DELETE v FROM companhia_aerea.venda v
        WHERE v.reserva_id = NEW.reserva_id;
    END IF;
end;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: got this response with that query: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7